# querying in angularjs returns much more than expected

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to extract all the users from my rails app

this is in my javascript file:

```
var app = angular.module('app');
app.factory('User', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/users/:id', {id: '@id'});
});

app.controller('UsersCtrl', ['$scope', 'User', function($scope, User) {    

    $scope.users = User.query();

});
```

However, when i try to use $scope.users in my views for my rails app, it shows an array of around 10000 when currently i have only one user. (It should only have one element in the array)

When i inspect $scope.users, it seems that is the html of that page

Comment: The obvious question is: do you have a route `/users/:id` which returns a JSON array of users on your API?

Answer (score 0):

`User.query()` will send a GET request to `/users` path. By default, the result of `.query()` calls will be an array.

`User.get({id: some_id})` will send a GET request to `/users/some_id`. By default, the result of `.get()` calls will be an object.